# angularJS: Wait for ng-if to finish, to make sure that the DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm using ng-if to show and hide an element. When the element shows up, I want to call a service, that scrolls within the new element to a certain child (by Id). The problem is, that if I try to call my service function right after setting the element to visible, the DOM doesn't seem to be ready yet.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory("ScrollService", function () {
    return {
        scroll: function (id) {
            console.log(document.getElementById(id));
        }
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, ScrollService) {
    $scope.visible = false;

    $scope.toggleVisibility = function () {
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
        if ($scope.visible) {
            ScrollService.scroll("myId"); //output: null
        }
    };
}
```

`document.getElementById()` will always result in `null`.

Here is also a fiddle, that demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Dpuq2/

So is there any way, to trigger a function as soon as the DOM is ready after being manipulated by ng-if?

**EDIT**

Using the fiddle of MinkoGechev, I was able to reproduce my error in a more realistic environment and with using a directive instead of a service: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dpuq2/2/)

The problem seems to occur, because I'm using `ng-repeat` inside of the `ng-if`-container:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-if="visible"> 
        <div id="myId" data-scroll="itemId">
            <div id="xy"></div>
            <div ng-repeat="item in items" id="{{ item.number }}">{{ item.number }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="toggleVisibility()">toggle</button>
</div>
```

Here is the according directive plus controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive("scroll", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            scroll: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$watch('scroll', function (v) {
                console.log(v, document.getElementById(scope.scroll));
            });
        },
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>"
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.visible = false;
    $scope.itemId = "";
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({
            number: i,
            text: "content " + i
        });
    }

    $scope.toggleVisibility = function () {
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
        if ($scope.visible) {
            $scope.itemId = "3";
        }
    };
}
```

So as soon as I toggle the visibility of my container, I'm setting the Id of the element, to which I want to scroll:

```
$scope.itemId = "3"
```

If I'm using one of the numbers from 1 to 10 (the Ids of the elements created by ng-repeat) it will fail. If I'm using "xy" (the Id of one element that lives next to the ng-repeat elements) it succeeds.

Comment: Please, don't implement DOM into controller, use directive instead

Comment: @MaximShoustin I didn't implement it into a controller, but into a service. I also tried using a directive, with the same result.

Comment: @basilikum In the `link()` function of a directive, you're sure the DOM of the element linked to this directive is ready. That's here that you must scroll the element to his child.

Comment: @Blackhole also a good suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be completely ready, since elements inside a ng-repeat, are not yet present (see updated question).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can achieve the effect you're looking for with directives:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive("scroll", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            scroll: '='
        },
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.$watch('scroll', function (v) {
                //The value is true, so the element is visible
                console.log(v, document.getElementById('myId'));
            });
        }
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.visible = false;

    $scope.toggleVisibility = function () {
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
    };
}
```

Here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/Dpuq2/1/) (open your console to see the logs).

**NOTE**: AngularJS force separation of concerns which leads to far more readable and maintainable code. One of the rules which you should follow while using "the Angular way" is to put all DOM manipulations **ONLY** inside directives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see that your fiddle works. Unfortunately, when I implement this into my app, it doesn't work anymore. Maybe there is something else going on. I'm going to respond again later.

Comment: I just edited my question. It seems, that the error has something to do with the use of ng-repeat. Do you have any idea, what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you found a solution to your problem?

Since you mention that the problem seems to be related to ng-repeat, have you tried "scope.$last?"

I am by no means an experienced web developer, but I have had a similar issue where a tooltip won't show on items "generated" by an ng-repeat and got it working with a directive that applied the tooltip using "scope.$last"

As an example:

```
AppName.directive('directiveName', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            <-- Your code here -->
        }
    };
});
```

Maybe someone with more experience could give some more input.